# How to test Python objects for non-equality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Lately, I have been writing lots of unit tests for the classes I have developed. This is the first time I have adopted the approach of rigorously testing my library code before releasing and I have to agree that I have 
learned a lot during the process.

The current challenge I face is with testing two instances for equality and non-equality.

Here is a simple class abstracting the library code:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.name == other.name and self.age == other.age

        return False
```

Here are the unit tests I have written for testing the equality functionality:

```
foo = User('Kshitij', 21)
bar = User('Leo', 30)

self.assertEqual(foo, User('Kshitij', 21))
self.assertNotEqual(foo, bar)
```

Both these test cases work fine. 
However, through the `assertNotEqual` method, I am testing the `__ne__()` of the `User` class. I find this somewhat misguiding since I have not implemented a custom `__ne__` method in my `User` class.

As a result of this dilemma, I thought of replacing the non-equality testcase with `self.assertFalse(foo.__eq__(bar))` or `self.assertFalse(foo == bar)`.

I understand that all these approaches perform the same task and this question might seem highly subjective at first. However, I am looking for some fundamental advice/principle about testing which can help me in similar predicaments.

Comment: Regardless of what your tests are testing, your code is going to *use* `!=`. You need to have tests for `!=`, and if your `!=` doesn't work, you need to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) is a good resource for this kind of question:

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`. There are no other implied relationships among the comparison operators, for example, the truth of (`x<y` or `x==y`) does not imply `x<=y`. To automatically generate ordering operations from a single root operation, see `functools.total_ordering()`.

That means it's totally fine to test: `self.assertNotEqual(foo, bar)` because by implementing `__eq__` and not overriding `__ne__` you *implicitly* defined `__ne__`.

But you don't need to test this explicitly (but you can) because it's one of the data-model guarantees.

---

However there is one thing that could lead to problems (bugs) which should be covered in the unit-tests:

The

```
if isinstance(other, self.__class__)
```

is kind of a red-flag (the `isinstance` and `self.__class__` combination).

In this specific case it wouldn't work if you deal with sub-classes (because then `self.__class__` can be the subclass).

You should either hardcode the base class:

```
if isinstance(other, User):
```

or use duck-typing:

```
try:
    return self.name == other.name and self.age == other.age
except AttributeError:
    return False
```

or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for this. Lesson learnt.
But isn't explicit better than implicit? ;)

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi In my opinion it's explicit because you **explicitly** didn't re-implemented `__ne__`. I mean the data model gives the guarantee - that should count for something. Only for a few classes it's actually useful to explicitly override `__ne__`. However I found a problem in your code regarding the `isinstance` check and updated the answer.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: The original rich comparison design *did* require you to explicitly define both `__eq__` and `__ne__`. Turns out people forget and forget and forget, and in Python 3, they decided it was more practical to provide `__ne__` for people automatically. That's also when they started automatically disabling `__hash__` for you if you override `__eq__` without handling `__hash__`.

Answer (score 0):

While doing objects comparison, by default Python checks something like objects' memory addresses (iirc, `id(obj)` values)

You should manually override both `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` methods.

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to reply to my query. However, this doesn't answer my question completely.